# SQL Injection Prevention WAF Generic Rule for Wordpress

Tags: php, sql-injection, wordpress, protection, waf

We are trying to develop a GENERIC WAF Rule for SQLI Prevention for WordPress-based websites that can provide some level of effectiveness with a very low probability of having false positives.

From my understanding I think we can provide some level of protection by default using these things:

1. Matching for table_names, information_schema, etc.
2. Matching for common SQLI Payload-based keywords like 'UNION', 'SELECT' etc. (This is prone to false positives because of a lot of common English words.) If > 2 matches then we can block.

If required, we can create a rule for each subcategory like Union-based, Error-based, time-based, AND/OR-based.

Like for Blind-based, we can consider the fact that they need to send a higher number of requests.

We are creating a generic rule so we don't expect it to block all bad requests.

SQLI is a serious issue for WordPress plugins mostly because of developers' mistakes and the PHP ecosystem. So, a preinstalled generic rule can provide at least some protection.

Is this a good idea?
Is this question too open-ended?
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could take a look at the ModSecurity coreruleset for inspiration: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf As you can see they use multiple rules which they combine to estimate whether a request should be blocked or not.